Add Column with a count of other columns that have any value in
My data frame is similar to below:
Name   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6    
A      Y    Y         Y             
B      Y         Y    Y         Y
C           Y    Y          Y       
D      Y    

I want to add a column that counts the other columns containing a value similar to:
Name   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6  Score
A      Y    Y         Y               3
B      Y         Y    Y         Y     4
C           Y    Y          Y         3
D      Y                              1

I have tried the following but with no success:
df['Score'] = df.count(df[['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']], axis='columns')


Are there missing values or empty strings?

They are missing values. Sorry, I should have put in NaN

If there are missing values use DataFrame.count with subset of columns:
df['Score'] = df[['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']].count(axis=1)
print (df)
  Name Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6  Score
0    A    Y    Y  NaN    Y  NaN  NaN      3
1    B    Y  NaN    Y    Y  NaN    Y      4
2    C  NaN    Y    Y  NaN    Y  NaN      3
3    D    Y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      1


Or use filter to subset: df['Score'] = df.filter(like = 'Col', axis=1).count(axis=1)

If I wanted a count of (different) columns including only values over 0, could I adapt this code for that?

@EdJefferies - then use df[['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']].gt(0).sum(axis=1)

count will consider empty strings as valid.
Assuming empty cells are '' , you can use ne and sum:
df['Score'] = df[['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']].ne('').sum(axis=1)

Or:
df['Score'] = df[['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']].eq('Y').sum(axis=1)

Output:
  Name Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6  Score
0    A    Y    Y         Y                3
1    B    Y         Y    Y         Y      4
2    C         Y    Y         Y           3
3    D    Y                               1


Thank you, I have gone with the answer above but you have given me two great examples I will store away for future use :)
